# Is it true that $log(i) = \frac\pi2i$ ? If so, are both of these legitimate proofs? They seem too beautiful not to be...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Sorry if this is a naive question. I have not yet taken any upper level math courses involving complex numbers. However, in preparation for those courses, together with utilizing the knowledge that mathematicians such as Euler would just play around with infinite series, led me to this result. This seems too beautiful not to be true. If it is true, could someone explain the general framework from which this is derived?

Statement: $$log(i) = \frac\pi2i$$
Proof One: By Euler's Identity $e^{ix} = cos{x} + isin{x}$

So that $$e^{\frac\pi2i} = cos\frac\pi2 + isin\frac\pi2 = i$$
But $$e^{log(i)} = i$$
Thus $$e^{log(i)} = e^{\frac\pi2i}$$
So that $$log(i) = \frac\pi2i$$
Proof Two: Using Power Series
$$log(i) = log(\frac{2i}2) = log\left(\frac{(1+i)(1+i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}\right) = log\left(\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right) = log(1+i) - log(1-i)$$
But $$ log(1+i) = i - \frac{i^2}2 + \frac{i^3}3 - \frac{i^4}4 + ...$$
And $$-log(1-i) = i + \frac{i^2}2 + \frac{i^3}3 + \frac{i^4}4 + ...$$
Thus $$log(1+i) - log(1-i) = 2\{i + \frac{i^3}3 + \frac{i^5}5 + \frac{i^7}7 + ...\} = 2i\{1 - \frac13 + \frac15 - \frac17 + ...\} = 2i\frac\pi4 = \frac\pi2i$$
Therefore $$log(i) = \frac\pi2i$$

Added June 4, 2016: I found a delightful identity for logarithms of complex quantites in general as opposed to the case $a+bi = i$. Since the proof is essentially a generalization of my proof that $log(i) = \frac{\pi}{2}i$ as well as being aesthetically pleasing I thought it was worth posting.

Statement: $$log\left(a+bi\right) = \frac{1}{2}log\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right) + itan^{-1}\frac{b}{a}$$

Proof: $$log\left(a+bi\right) = log\left({\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}{\frac{a+bi} {\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}log\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right) + log\left({\frac{a+bi}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}}\right)$$

Now, $$log\left({\frac{a+bi}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}}\right) = log\left({\frac{1+i\frac{b}{a}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{b^{2}}{a^2}}}}\right) = log\left({1+i\frac{b}{a}}\right) - \frac{1}{2}log\left(1+\frac{b^{2}}{a^2}\right)$$

But, $$log\left(1+i\frac{b}{a}\right) = \left(i\frac{b}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{2}{\left(i\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{2} + \frac{1}{3}{\left(i\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{3} - \frac{1}{4}{\left(i\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{4} +... = 
i\left( \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{3}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{3} + \frac{1}{5}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{5} - \frac{1}{7}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{7} +... \right) +
\\ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{4}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{4} + \frac{1}{6}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{6} - \frac{1}{8}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{8} +...$$
And,$$ \frac{1}{2}log\left(1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\left({\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left({\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}}\right)^{2} + \frac{1}{3}\left({\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}}\right)^{3} - \frac{1}{4}\left({\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}}\right)^{4} +...\right) = \\ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{4}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{4} + \frac{1}{6}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{6} - \frac{1}{8}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{8} +...$$
So that, $$log\left({1+i\frac{b}{a}}\right) - \frac{1}{2}log\left(1+\frac{b^{2}}{a^2}\right) = i\left( \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)-\frac{1}{3}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{3} + \frac{1}{5}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{5} - \frac{1}{7}{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{7} +... \right) = itan^{-1}{\frac{b}{a}}$$
Therefore, $$log(a+bi) = \frac{1}{2}log(a^{2}+b^{2}) + itan^{-1}\frac{b}{a}$$ 
Example: Let a=0 and b=1 and we have 
$$log(i) = itan^{-1}\infty = \frac{\pi}{2}i + 2\pi mi$$

Comment: you should remember adding a $2 i m\pi $ term everywhere, just to be sure :) $\log(1-z) =2 i \pi m+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}$ for every$|z| < 1$,  and $m =0$ being one of the possible branches

Comment: and you would conclude with $\log(i) = 2i m \pi + i \pi / 2$, which is the correct answer

Comment: I guess now I'll have to go learn how $log(1-z) = 2i\pi m + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^{k}}k$ is derived. Math is so cool!

Comment: sorry I forgot a $-$ sign. nothing complicated you already got it : everywhere it is differentiable $(-\log(1-z))' = \frac{1}{1-z}$, and we also need $\log(1) = 2 i m \pi$ since $e^{\log(1)} = 1$, hence ..

Comment: and remember [that the complex logarithm looks like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#/media/File:Riemann_surface_log.svg

Comment: This is my mental picture of what you've said, I hope this isn't butchering it too much. 
$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...$ 
Integrating both sides yields $-log(1-x) = x + \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 + \frac{x^4}4 + ...$ But $-log(1-x) = -log(1-x) - log(1) = -log(1-x) - 2im\pi$  
Thus $-log(1-x) = 2im\pi + x + \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 + \frac{x^4}4 + ...$

Comment: yes but no, the $2im \pi$ appears as the integration constant when integrating $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and obtaining $\int \frac{1}{1-x} dx = -\log(1-x)+C$

Comment: OK that makes sense. Truth be told I don't have a solid conceptual grasp of what the constant of integration is. I'm taking Cal II this semester but I've just been so enamored by the formalism that I haven't payed much attention to the logical underpinnings of Integration.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you define "logarithm" in the first place. But the simplest and most straightforward approach would be to define

> **Definition.** $\log x$ means the number $y$ such that $e^y=x$.

With this definition the first two lines of your first proof is a complete, direct proof that $\log i = \frac12\pi i$.

The only problem is that with this reasoning $\log i$ can *also* be shown to be $\frac52\pi i$ and $\frac 92\pi i$ and $\frac{13}2\pi i\ldots$ because the exponential function of those numbers are *also* $i$.

This is not just a minor deficiency of the definition, though -- **the complex logarithm is inherently multivalued** in the precise sense that it is *not* possible to define a single function that is continuous on all of $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ such that $e^{f(z)}=z$ everywhere.

The usual fudging one does in order to overcome this is to speak of the "principal logarithm", notated $\operatorname{Log}$ with a capital L, and define

> $\operatorname{Log} z$ means the number $y$ such that $e^y=x$ and the imaginary part of $y$ is in $(-\pi,\pi]$.

This is, unfortunately, discontinuous on the negative real axis, but we can't really do better.

---

Your **second proof** is an ingenious manipulation, but of a kind that will easily lead to nonsense if you're not careful. Basically you're taking the power series for $\log(1+z)$ which will only work for $|z|\le 1, z\ne -1$ and then just *assuming* that this extends to a function on all of $\mathbb C\setminus 0$ that satisfies the usual logarithm rules everywhere. But this is not the case -- with the same reasoning we could say
$$ 1 = \Bigl(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\Bigr)^8 $$
so
$$ 0 = \log 1 = 8\log\Bigl(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\Bigr) $$
which requires the logarithm on the right to be $0$ -- but actually the series will yield $\frac14\pi i$.

This is the multi-valuedness of the logarithm that strikes again -- it *is not possible* for any nontrivial differentiable function on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ to satisfy $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$ everywhere.

Comment: Wow thanks, your explanations make sense. I see what you mean about just assuming that the logarithm rules will hold 'willy nilly.' It's a shame though that the formal manipulation isn't entirely justified in this case.

Comment: @BeautyIsTruth Well, $8\log\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)=\log(1)$, but not the other way around.

Comment: @SimpleArt : $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ leads to $\log(1) \ne \log(1)$, you have to write $8 \log((1+i)/\sqrt{2}) = \log(1) + 2 i m \pi$, and in general (if $ab \ne 0$) then $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b) +2i m \pi$ for some integer $m$ that you can choose as you wish, that's the multi-valuedness of $\log$ as said Henning...

Answer (score -3):

From Euler's identity $$e^{i\pi/2} = cos(\pi/2) + i sin(\pi/2) = i
$$

Take the natural log of both sides.

The left $\ln(e^{i\pi/2}) = i\pi/2$ and the right is simply $\ln i$.

Since both are equal,  $i\pi/2 = \ln i.$

So, it is not arbitrary log but ln. Otherwise, your identity is correct.